# Detach from screen without Ctrl+a d in SSH

Tags: gnu-screen

I'm running a set of processes using the `screen` command on my Ubuntu server. The idea is that the process should ideally not be cancelled or be under the risk of being cancelled by mistake

I find that using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> is a really risky hotkey for detaching the screen, since using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> terminates it.

Is there any way to change the detach hotkey to something else? For example, can I change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>?

I tried using an alias, but that didn't work for keyboard commands.

Comment: Just checking - are you pressing Ctrl+a, letting go of those and then pressing d, or are you trying to press all 3 at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this from the screen man page.

To view the bindings in use, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, release and then press <kbd>?</kbd>.

As you indicated <kbd>d</kbd> is used to detach.

To change bindings on the fly, you can enter a command mode by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> then press <kbd>:</kbd>

To set a binding, type `bind <key> <command>`. So to set a new binding for detach type `bind z detach`.

To remove an existing binding you omit the command portion. So to remove an existing binding for <kbd>d</kbd>, you type `bind d`.

All together...

1. Remove <kbd>d</kbd> binding for detach by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> then press <kbd>:</kbd>. Then type `bind d`
2. Remove <kbd>^D</kbd> binding by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> then press <kbd>:</kbd>. Then type `bind ^D`
3. Add your own binding by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> then press <kbd>:</kbd>. Then type `bind <YOUR_KEY> detach`

You can place these commands in a `.screenrc` in the user's home directory to make them persist.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me!